# Why wordpress change url automatically when using query string page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress page and when i try to add query string to my page. 
 **Ex**:

> my-page/list-companies?page=2

Wordpress will redirect me to:

> my-page/list-companies/2

I dont know the problem is in my code or wordpress settings, can anyone help me with that because i tried google but still no results. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
The problem was the parameter ?page=2, which may cause wordpress missunderstanding (i guess), the solution is change the permalink to **Plain** or change parameter to something else: **?current_page=2**. Thank you for supporting me !

Comment: This is not an issue in coding. All you need to do is, edit url redirection in .htaccess. You can also find it in settings.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Check permalinks under settings tab in administration and set how URL should look

Answer (score 0):

Goto Settings - Permalinks
And select Post-name (most popular)